# if else statement confused c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int positiveInteger;

    cout << "Please input an integer up to 100." << endl;

    cin >> positiveInteger;

    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= positiveInteger; i++)
    {
        if ( positiveInteger >= 0 )
        {
          result += i;
        }
        else 
        {
          cout << "Please input a positive integer." << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

Above I have a `for` loop with an if else statement in the center. I am confused because I want it to be so when I enter a integer that is not negative it will loop the if result. But I want it to be so if I put in a negative number it says please input a positive integer. That's why I set it so in the if statement only numbers above and = to 0 would return the result, but if I enter a negative number I just get 0 I want it to say "Please input a positive integer". I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Isn't the if statement if true pulls the if and if its not true pulls the else? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Wait i just realize result returns the 0 but still why wont it say please input an integer thats positive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got it right, you want to
1. input a number;
2.1 If the number is positive you loop through it.
2.2 If it's negative you show the error message.

The problem is your loop, where the conditional is, checks if i (which is zero) is smaller then the number. However if you input a negative number i will be bigger then positiveInteger and you won't loop through the if. I fixed your code

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int positiveInteger;

    cout << "Please input an integer up to 100." << endl;

    cin >> positiveInteger;

    int result = 0;
    if ( positiveInteger >= 0 ){
       for (int i = 0; i <= positiveInteger; i++)
       {
           result += i;
       }
       cout << result;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Please input a positive integer." << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Wow thats interesting i didnt think to put a forloop in the inside.

Comment: I also put the `cout << result ` inside the if statement so it doesnt return 0 when i print please input a positive!

Comment: Yep, actually I missed that one. You do should do that for the reasons you mentioned yourself :)

Comment: @David Wolever: Thanks for the edit, I just came back for that :)

Answer (score 4):

If you enter a negative number, you never get to enter the loop. An approach that fits better to such cases is:

```
do
{
    input a number;
    if( positive )
         do something;
} while( not positive );
```

Comment: is this considered a do while loop?

Comment: Oh i just havent studied this yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code would benefit from some rearrangement. I'd structure it something like this:

```
do { 
    cout << "please enter a number between 1 and 100";
    number = get_number():
} while (number < 1 || number > 100);

cout << sum_series(1, number);
```

Comment: Ah i havent learned this do while looping yet. So do while would be more efficient from my understanding?

Comment: It's less efficiency than logic: you always want to read the number at least once, which is what a do/while loop is intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

The output you are getting is because your loop fails at non-negative numbers. You should try the following:

```
int main()
{

int positiveInteger;

cout << "Please input an integer upto 100." << endl;

cin >> positiveInteger;

int result = 0;
if ( positiveInteger < 0 )
{

    cout << "Please input a positive integer." << endl;

}
else{


   for (int i = 0; i <= positiveInteger; i++)
   {

    result += i;

   }

 cout << result;

 }
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, if the number is negative, you wish to take another input. But the `cin` statement is not under loop control to do it so. It just executes only one time irrespective of the nature of the number.